# Jquery mobile all the events are called twice

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4.1, Jquery 1.11 and Html5.

Please help me understand this [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ashu111/rkVEW/) try running the html and see the below behaviour.

A. Provide username field and click submit.Now from page2  click "search" button and note that two times submit handler is called.

B. Click Logout and verify that two times the click handler is called.

C. Again provide username field and click submit. Even this handler is called twice.

1. What is wrong with my code? If I uncomment the all the occurrences .off("submit","#searchFormID"), it works fine.

Something to do with bind and unbind.Which I am unable to understand. Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page"  id="page1" data-ajax="false">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>page1 header</h1>
  </div>

   <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div id="userForm">
        <form data-ajax="false" method="POST" >
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="uname" >Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username" required autofocus data-theme="e" data-clear-btn="true">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">
        </form>
    </div>
   </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" >
    <h1>page1 footer</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-ajax="false">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>page2 Header</h1>
    <a data-ajax="false" id="logoutID" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-right">Logout</a>
  </div>

   <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div id="searchFormDiv" >
        <form id="searchFormID" data-ajax="false" method="POST"> 
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label for="searchID">Search Input:</label>
                <input type="search" name="search" data-theme="b" id="searchID" required autofocus placeholder="Enter ID"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" value="Search" data-theme="b">
        </form>
   </div>
   <div id="searchResult"></div>
 </div>

 <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
   <h1>page2 Footer</h1>
 </div>

</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {` attach event on a specific page. Whenever a page is created, the code will be multiplied. if you have 10 pages, `submit` will fire 10 times.

Comment: Thank You Omar for the guidance. So what is the best way to avoid this. Or I am doing the correct way first detach and then attach it.$(document).off("submit","#searchFormID").on("submit","#searchFormID",function (event) {

Comment: it possible too, you can do it this way too, by attaching once only using `.one()` i.e. `$(document).one("pagecreate"`.

Comment: Omar.. Thank You very much. Before I post here I searched a lot to find or read the reasons behind the handler getting called multiple times.but I could'nt.. How do keep updated/learn about such things??? Please guide me.

Comment: You're welcome :) by simply understanding jQM page events, how they work and when they do fire, and a bit of _trial and error_, then you'll master jQM ;)

Comment: Sure. I will.. but these tricky things are not documented even in jquery docs.At least i am unable to find.Could you please point some good books or sites which explain in detail such core concepts.

Comment: I really dont know any books, never read any in fact. You will get to know them by practicing and solving jQM _puzzles_. This is my advice for you.